# Deleting element in a python list iterated by index

Tags: python, list, loops

folks

i have the following code:

```
for i in range(len(self.corpses)):
    for j in range(len(self.corpses))[i+1:]:
        if self.corpses[i].collides(self.corpses[j]):
            self.corpses[i] = self.corpses[i] + self.corpses[j]
            self.corpses.remove(self.corpses[j])
```

but this keeps going out of index.I would like to know what I do to remove the `corpse` under those conditions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are getting the `IndexError` because when you remove an item from the list, you are changing the list length.

Comment: I know... But what I can do to remove the corpse under the conditions above?

Comment: One solution may be catching `IndexError` and breaking out of the loop.

Comment: I did not understand why i am getting downvotes....

Comment: Seems like an X-Y problem.

Comment: Undestand... I will try not to do that next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You changed the length of the list. You could use a while loop instead:

```
i, l = 0, len(self.corpses)
while i < l:
    j = i + 1
    while j < l:
        if self.corpses[i].collides(self.corpses[j]):
            self.corpses[i] = self.corpses[i] + self.corpses[j]
            del self.corpses[j]
            l -= 1
        else:
            j += 1
    i += 1
```

This way you keep full control over all changes.